# Ubuntu 16.04 ping to gateway works, ping to other win pc does not work

Tags: 16.04, server

I'm new to Ubuntu and started to like Linux but when I have problem with Linux, I have no idea what else to do. I have searched Google but none of the methods works. 
Gateway 
192.168.1.1
Other win 10 pcs
192.198.1.8
Ping to 192.168.1.8 100% packet loss and also 8.8.8.8
I have checked my /etc/network/interfaces seems to be normal with dhcp setup
Where do I have to look? Please help.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is on Windows. In most installations by default, Windows doesn't answer to ping requests.